# log4j reading config file error

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have java web application deployed in Tomcat. I created a classes folder under WEB-INF and had log4j.properties file under it. I want the logger to be appended in a file.

**log4j.properties file :**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA

# AdminFileAppender - used to log messages in the admin.log file.
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.File=admin.log
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# ReportFileAppender - used to log messages in the report.log file.
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.File=report.log
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.sample.cfd=WARN,AdminFileAppender 
log4j.logger.com.sample.cfd=DEBUG,ReportFileAppender
```

**Code in Servlet**

```
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CfdServlet.class);
 dpPost(...){
     PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
     logger.debug("Sample debug message");
 }
```

**Error Message :**

I get the following error as its not able to find my configuration file under **WEB_INF/classes/log4j.properties**

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Is something wrong in the location of my properties file.

Comment: is it being packaged inside the war file?

Comment: Hi Dan, I can see it being packaged in war file

Comment: Where is the location of the file in WAR? It must be in a folder included in classpath. WEB-INF/classes can be a good place for it. To do this, you must put the file in a source folder.

Comment: As i mentioned above, I'm creating a file under the same location you suggested. But my application is not picking up from this path. I'm using eclipse. And its looking for a dynamic path where eclipse is deploying. "/Users/satishjonnala/eclipse copy/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS". I changed the path by using the contextpath and its working.